Multiplying numpy arrays across different axis
Let's say I have two arrays:
a = [
     [[-1, 0, 1], 
      [-2, 0, 2],
      [-3, 0, 3]],

     [[-4, 0, 4],
      [-5, 0, 5],
      [-6, 0, 6]]
    ] 

and
b = [
     [1, 3, 5],
     [7, 11, 13]
    ]

I'm trying to find the most elegant way to end up with the output
c = [
     [[-1, 0, 1], 
      [-6, 0, 6],
      [-15, 0, 15]],

     [[-28, 0, 28],
      [-55, 0, 55],
      [-78, 0, 78]]
    ] 

Is there some sort of function in numpy that can handle this elegantly?
I've browsed the documentation for np.multiply() and np.dot() and I haven't found a nice way to do it with those functions. I've suppose I could make some sort of ugly for loop to do it in, but I'm hoping for something more elegant.

you can do it using broadcasting
firstly you need to check for the shapes of the array if they are not the same so you can board casting
c= a[:, :, None] * b[None, :, :]

print(c)


Thank you tremendously. For anyone wondering in the future, I found that c = a * b[:, :, None] was the broadcasting required to get the answer in the original question.
